# d3 js drag event listener isnt getting the event - (d3, react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to add drag event to my d3 force layout, but for some reason, the event attr isn't defined so nothing happens. I know there were changes in the new doc of d3-drag and I followed these instructions.

heres my code:

```
    const node = svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 35) // radius field, so width and height 80X80
      .attr("stroke", "lightgray")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
      .style("fill", "lightgray")
      .call(handler
      .on('start', dragstarted)
      .on('drag', dragged)
      .on('end', dragended)
```

the event functions:

```
    const dragstarted = (event: any, d: any) => {
      console.log(' dragged d', d);
      console.log('event', event);

      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore
      if (!event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      }
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    const dragged = (event: any, d: any) => {
      console.log(' dragged d', d);
      console.log('event', event);

      d.fx = event.x;
      d.fy = event.y;
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    const dragended = (event: any, d: any) => {
      console.log(' dragended  d', d);
      console.log('event', event);

      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore
      if (event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      }

      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }
```

the example from the docs :

```
  d3.drag()
       .on("start", (event, d) => circle.filter(p => p === d).raise().attr("stroke", "black"))
       .on("drag", (event, d) => (d.x = event.x, d.y = event.y))
       .on("end", (event, d) => circle.filter(p => p === d).attr("stroke", null))
```

and this is what i get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
    at nodrag.js:5
```

I added screenshots for the place its failing to get the event

[image: the event that isn't there]

[image: the error]

I don't get what I do wrong here, thanks for the help.

**EDIT**
full example with the code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-saqrv9?file=src%2Fgraph.tsx

Comment: What version of d3 are you using? It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of your code, preferably in a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). That way, we can more easily answer your question and you'll be more likely to get a good answer!

Comment: You're right ! here's a stackblitz with the current code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-saqrv9?file=src%2Fgraph.tsx

Comment: answer : versoining issues ):

Answer (score 0):

notice that the new API isn't using d3.event but the event passed to the event listener.

updated snippet for example for anyone who is interested, I know there's not many examples out there, so have fun

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-saqrv9?file=src%2Fgraph.tsx